# How do I delete a sticky + highlights in Adobe Reader X?

Tags: adobe-reader

What are the keyboard shortcuts or in-program buttons in Adobe Reader X to delete a sticky note and highlights?  When I click on a sticky or around it there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to delete a sticky once it has been opened.  And how do I remove the highlighter marks from a sentence?

Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Reader X on MacOS X: To delete a highlight, click on it then press Function+Delete, i.e. the real Delete key, not the Backspace key labelled Delete!

If you have applied more than one highlight to a piece of text, repeat the click and Function+Delete to remove each layer of highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have text highlighted in your pdf, you should do the following:

1. Click on **Tools → Content Editing Edit Text & Images**
2. Hover your mouse to one of the edges of the text field on the document until you see the symbol with the four arrows.
3. Left click and drag the text box away to an open area on that page.
4. Hover over the highlight section and right click.
5. Click on "Delete" in the menu that appears and you should be good to go...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried this myself but [this blog post](http://alamoxie.com/blog/tech-tips/highlighting-sticky-notes-adobe-reader/) suggests:

> To delete a sticky note, just click it–either the sticky note icon on
>   the page or the sticky note item in the comments pane–and press the
>   delete button.

and:

> To delete a highlight, just click it–either the highlighted text or
>   the highlight item in the comments pane–and press the delete button.

There’s a screencast on the link as well.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Drag the textbox away from the highlights, you ll notice that the high remain behind. Click on the highlights (they are just harmless yellow boxes now) and press delete. And move the textbox back into its original position.

Voila (took me hours to figure out)