# Separate highlight and comments in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, highlighting

I am working with another person, so I have to read tons of PDFs and:

- highlight what I think it is important for later reading
- make comments in the PDF, about what I don't understand, and send it to him.

He, conversely, needs to:

- read my doubts in a quick and efficient way and answer them.

My problem is: 
Adobe Reader use the same tool for highlight AND comment, so when he goes to read the comments, he has to go through lots of empty highlights.
[image]

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/410647/how-do-i-delete-a-sticky-highlights-in-adobe-reader-x

Answer (score 1):

Highlights and "comments" are all annotations, and therefore very much related.

One possibility would be to use the underline tool for your (logical) comments. Then your partner can sort by type.

In older versions of Acrobat, it was also possible to sort by color, but there is now a "feature" in Acrobat which no longer allows for that, which means that different colors do not work.

Another possibility would be using another login name for the (logical) comments; sorting by name is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Adobe Reader use the same tool for highlight AND comment, ...

This isn't necessarily the case. You can attach a comment to a highlight annotation, but you can also create separate comments (usually known as "notes" in PDFs) with a separate tool. Just looking at your screenshot, the two tools are evident here:

[image: Note and Highlight tools in Adobe Reader]

If you use them separately, the recipient of your file can sort their comment list by type and thus distinguish the comments.